# What is the mechanism of death by poisoning?

Tags: death, medicine, science, soul

The four deaths mentioned in the Jewish law have a very straightforward physical impact on the body. All of them cause inability to breathe which is linked to "maintenance" of the soul, and thus cause death:

- Crushing the chest and the lungs by stoning
- Decapitating
- Burning the throat and the trachea
- Strangling

I find it difficult, however, to explain a death caused by a drop of poison - there's no physical damage is caused to the body and no disruption to breathing.

How do our sources explain the mechanism of death by poisoning?

Comment: when is poisoning used as a mechanism of judicial punishment?

Comment: Why do you associate stoning with damage to the lungs specifically, and not other vital organs? IIRC, the mishnah in Sanhedrin says the  stone is aimed at his heart.

Comment: It depends which sort of poison, CO for example binds very strongly with haemoglobin and prevents oxygen binding with the haemoglobin, so effectively strangles you. But *ve'chi mah inyan shmittah etzel har sinai*?

Comment: He's not asking about judicial punishment

Comment: @robev then why start with a list of four methods of judicial killing as precedents? Death by exsanguination likewise is not about breathing, nor is having a piano dropped on your head.

Comment: Ask him. I believe she's saying he understands how death works with the capital punishments, but not other forms of dying.

Comment: @rosends I understood that the four methods relate directly to damaging breathing, leading to death (as if connected to the soul). Poisoning does not affect breathing. How is this death explained?

Comment: I think I phrased it clearly about the MECHANISM of affecting the soul.

Comment: are you saying that poisoning is one of these four? If not, why would it follow the same logic?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean about death by poison because that isn't one of the four ways Beis Din carries out capital punishment  so I'm assuming  you mean burning the throat and the trachea (Serafa) which is done by a drop of poison rather than the use of actual fire.

The Rambam Sahedrin 15:3 describes it as follows

וּמַתִּיכִים אֶת הַבְּדִיל וְאֶת הָעוֹפֶרֶת וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן וְהוּא זוֹרֵק לְתוֹךְ פִּיו וְהִיא יוֹרֶדֶת **וְשׂוֹרֶפֶת** אֶת בְּנֵי מֵעָיו

*Tin, lead, and the like are melted down and then poured into his mouth. The molten metal descends and **burns** his innards.*

IOW the poison used does in fact cause physical damage.

Comment: But this is *sereifa*?

Comment: Yes . They didn't use fire and burn people at the stake. They burnt the person's inside

Comment: Yes agreed, the question was about poisoning however. The *halacha* is that if the person who is sentenced is escaping, then *beis din* can kill him anyway they like. So I suppose they could poison him if there is no alternative.

Comment: How do you poison someone who is escaping?

Comment: Or who has escaped...